# Advanced Custom Fields Default Values Based On Current User

Tags: wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

How to set product field value based on current user's display name in ACF plugin?

Following acf/load_field[acf/load_field filter documentation][1] I tried adding this to my functions.php:

```
function acf_load_user_display_name( $field ){ $user = wp_get_current_user(); $display_name = $user->display_name; return $user->display_name; } // acf/load_field - default for product_display_name field add_filter('acf/load_field/name=product_display_name', 'acf_load_user_display_name');
```

This code makes a bug on the edit-product page and ACF-edit-field groups, and the custom field "product_display_name" is still blank on the product page.
[1]: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/